# How to find the cumulative distribution for the following situation

Tags: simulation

So, I have been provided with the following situation. We need to define $F(x)$ when we toss a die and if the die is $1 \ \ or\ \  2$, then we generate a uniform random variate between $0 \ \ and \ \  2$. If the die is $3 or 4$, then we generate a uniform random variate between $2\ \  and \ \ 3$ and if the die is $5 \ \ or \ \  6$, then we generate a uniform random variate between $4 \ \ and \ \  6$. We need to find $F(x)$ in order to inversion method.

I have no idea how to find $F(x)$, but I know that probability of get 2 sides in die tossing, will be $1/3$, but I don't know how to proceed further. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Find $F$ using the definition: compute the probability that the result is less than or equal to $x.$ Separately consider values $x$ between $0$ and $2,$ between $2$ and $3,$ and between $4$ and $6.$

Comment: ummm, I really dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Ask yourself the simplest possible questions at first.  For instance (1) what is the chance the result is negative? (2) what is the chance it is $2$ or smaller?  Go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $F$ has a mixture distribution of three cases,

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{0,2}}(x)+\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{2,3}}(x)+\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{4,6}}(x).$$

The result follows from conditional expectation.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
F(x)&=&P(X\leq x)\\
&=&E[P(X\leq x|D)]\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}P(X\leq x|D=\{1,2\})+\frac{1}{3}P(X\leq x|D=\{3,4\})+\frac{1}{3}P(X\leq x|D=\{5,6\})\\
&=&\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{0,2}}(x)+\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{2,3}}(x)+\frac{1}{3}F_{U_{4,6}}(x)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Good luck for you!